# Visual bug when at log in screen

Tags: 14.04, drivers, login, screen, cinnamon

A couple of months ago I installed 14.04 and since I did so my screen always bugs out after I type out my password and hit enter. This is what it looks like:

#### Login screen

[image]

It does this for about a minute then it's fine afterwards. The background is always purple and the login box is always white for some reason. I've tried to fix it but nothing has worked.

#### Desktop

[image]

Just recently I have moved from Unity to Cinnamon and in doing so I purged Unity thinking it would fix my purple background issues. It didn't work, so I'm having troubles finding what's messing up the login screen. The desktop looks perfectly fine and I never have this issue anywhere else except for when I log in.

The running resolution is 1600x900 (native res of my Dell Inspiron N7010) and I use Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller on an Intel Pentium.

Comment: Please add the following information to your question: What resolution are you running at?  Which video card (or on-board graphics chip) are you using?

Comment: I see the same thing typically and i have an Intel Integrated 3000 or 4000 chipset on a laptop. Historically Ive seen such visual glitches across many distributions over many years of laptops.

Answer (score 2):

After a coupe days of searching I finally came to a conclusion. The reason I was getting the purple background was the file that Ubuntu tweak was using as the login background no longer existed. After moving my chosen background to `/usr/share/backgrounds` I now have an actual background and no weird screen tearing.